# Schedule AlarmManager Android

Tags: android, operating-system, alarmmanager

Can I schedule alarm manager (.set() methode) in android to a time which is one month later the current time 
will it be alive for that mutch of time ?
what will be the OS effects on this alarmManager ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tip for a case when user reboots his phone. You can declare BroadcastReceiver with the following intent-filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
```

and re-schedule your alarm in `onReceive(...)` of your receiver class. Intent will be delivered to the receiver after user reboots his phone. Don't forget to add the following permission to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Or you can use the library that will handle such cases for you:
https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically yes, If the user keeps his phone on for that long, however the alarm doesn't survive reboots and will therefore not be scheduled when the phone restarts.